# Изменение горизонтального бара в графике на вертикальный (CSS)

Tags: html, css

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/odroqubs/). Помогите перестроить горизонтальный бар графика на вертикальный (повернуть фигуру на 90°) и ось "X" расположить сверху, чтобы получилось примерно вот так:

[image]

```
body
    {
    margin: 50px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    }

/* ==================== BAR GRAPH  ==================== */

/* ------ container ------ */
div.css_bar_graph
    {
    width: 580px;
    height: 320px;
    padding: 40px 20px 10px 70px;
    /* --- font --- */
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #444444;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    position: relative; 
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto; 
    border: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
    /* --- css3 --- */
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    }

/* ------ hyperlinks ------ */
div.css_bar_graph a
    {
    color: #444444;
    text-decoration: none;
    }

/* ------ lists ------ */
div.css_bar_graph ul
    {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
    }

div.css_bar_graph li
    {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    }

/* ==================== Y-AXIS LABELS ==================== */


/* ------ base ------ */
div.css_bar_graph ul.y_axis
    {
    width: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    left: 10px;
    text-align: right;
    }

/* ------ labels ------ */
div.css_bar_graph ul.y_axis li
    {
    width: 100%;
    height: 24px;   /* 50px including border */
    float: left;
    color: #888888;
    /* --- alignment correction --- */
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
    position: relative;
    top: -13px; /* value = font height */
    }   

/* ==================== X-AXIS LABELS  ==================== */

/* ------ base ------ */
div.css_bar_graph ul.x_axis
    {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 90px;
    text-align: center;
    }

/* ------ labels ------ */
div.css_bar_graph ul.x_axis li
    {
    display: inline;
    width: 135px;
    float: left;
    }

/* ==================== GRAPH LABEL  ==================== */

/* ------ base ------ */
div.css_bar_graph div.label
    {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    }

div.css_bar_graph div.label span
    {
    font-weight: bold;
    }

/* ==================== GRAPH  ==================== */

/* ------ base ------ */
div.css_bar_graph div.graph
    {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    }

/* ------ grid ------ */
div.css_bar_graph div.graph ul.grid
    {
    width: 100%;
    }

/* ------ IE grid ------ */
div.css_bar_graph div.graph li
    {
    width: 100%;
    height: 24px;   /* 50px including border */
    float: left;
    border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    }   

/* ------ other browsers grid ------ */
div.css_bar_graph div.graph li:nth-child(odd)
    {
    width: 100%;
    height: 24px;   /* 50px including border */
    float: left;
    border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    }

div.css_bar_graph div.graph li:nth-child(even)
    {
    width: 100%;
    height: 24px;   /* 50px including border */
    float: left;
    border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    }

/* ------ bottom grid element ------ */
div.css_bar_graph div.graph li.bottom
    {
    border-top: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    height: 19px;
    }

/* ==================== BARS COMMON  ==================== */

/* ------ common styles ------ */
div.css_bar_graph div.graph li.bar
    {
    width: 25px;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 75px;
    text-align: center;
    /* --- css3 --- */
    /* --- transitions --- */
    -webkit-transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
    }

/* ------ bar top circle ------ */
div.css_bar_graph div.graph li.bar div.top
    {
    width: 100%;
    height: 10px;
    margin-top: -5px;
    /* --- css3 --- */
    -moz-border-radius: 25px/10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 25px 10px;
    border-radius: 25px/10px;
    /* --- transitions --- */
    -webkit-transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
    }

/* ------ bar bottom circle ------ */
div.css_bar_graph div.graph li.bar div.bottom
    {
    width: 100%;
    height: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -5px;
    left: 0px;
    /* --- css3 --- */
    -moz-border-radius: 25px/10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 25px 10px;
    border-radius: 25px/10px;
    /* --- transitions --- */
    -webkit-transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
    }

/* ------ bar top label ------ */
div.css_bar_graph div.graph li.bar span
    {
    visibility: hidden; /* show label on mouse over */
    position: relative;
    top: -45px;
    padding: 3px 5px 3px 5px;
    z-index: 100;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    border: 1px solid #bebebe;
    /* --- css3 --- */
    border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    /* --- gradient --- */
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #f1f1f1 1px, #ebebeb); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#f1f1f1', endColorstr='#ebebeb'); /* IE5.5 - 7 */
    -ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#f1f1f1', endColorstr='#ebebeb'); /* IE8 */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #f1f1f1 1px, #ebebeb); /* IE9 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #f1f1f1 1px, #ebebeb); /* Firefox */ 
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #f1f1f1 1px, #ebebeb); /* Opera 11  */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #f1f1f1 1px, #ebebeb); /* Chrome 11  */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #ffffff), color-stop(0.05, #f1f1f1), color-stop(1, #ebebeb)); /* Chrome 10, Safari */
    /* --- shadow --- */
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,1);
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    /* --- transitions --- */
    -webkit-transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
    }

/* ------ bars positions ------ */
div.css_bar_graph div.graph li.nr_1
    {
    left: 110px;
    }

div.css_bar_graph div.graph li.nr_2
    {
    left: 145px;
    }

div.css_bar_graph div.graph li.nr_3
    {
    left: 180px;
    }

div.css_bar_graph div.graph li.nr_4
    {
    left: 245px;
    }

div.css_bar_graph div.graph li.nr_5
    {
    left: 280px;
    }

div.css_bar_graph div.graph li.nr_6
    {
    left: 315px;
    }

div.css_bar_graph div.graph li.nr_7
    {
    left: 380px;
    }

div.css_bar_graph div.graph li.nr_8
    {
    left: 415px;
    }

div.css_bar_graph div.graph li.nr_9
    {
    left: 450px;
    }

div.css_bar_graph div.graph li.nr_10
    {
    left: 515px;
    }

div.css_bar_graph div.graph li.nr_11
    {
    left: 550px;
    }

div.css_bar_graph div.graph li.nr_12
    {
    left: 585px;
    }

/* ==================== BLUE BAR  ==================== */

/* ------ base ------ */
div.css_bar_graph div.graph li.blue
    {
    background: #208faf;    /* --- IE --- */
    background: rgba(32,143,175,0.8);
    }

/* ------ top ------ */
div.css_bar_graph div.graph li.blue div.top
    {
    background: #72b8cc;
    }

/* ------ bottom ------ */
div.css_bar_graph div.graph li.blue div.bottom
    {
    background: #208faf;
    }

/* ==================== GREEN BAR  ==================== */

/* ------ base ------ */
div.css_bar_graph div.graph li.green
    {
    background: #608d00;    /* --- IE --- */
    background: rgba(96,141,0,0.8);
    }

/* ------ top ------ */
div.css_bar_graph div.graph li.green div.top
    {
    background: #a2c656;
    }

/* ------ bottom ------ */
div.css_bar_graph div.graph li.green div.bottom
    {
    background: #608d00;
    }

/* ==================== ORANGE BAR  ==================== */

/* ------ base ------ */
div.css_bar_graph div.graph li.orange
    {
    background: #ff9000;    /* --- IE --- */
    background: rgba(255,144,0,0.8);
    }

/* ------ top ------ */
div.css_bar_graph div.graph li.orange div.top
    {
    background: #ffc24c;
    }

/* ------ bottom ------ */
div.css_bar_graph div.graph li.orange div.bottom
    {
    background: #ff9000;
    }

/* ==================== PURPLE BAR  ==================== */

/* ------ base ------ */
div.css_bar_graph div.graph li.purple
    {
    background: #7d47ba;    /* --- IE --- */
    background: rgba(125,71,186,0.8);
    }

/* ------ top ------ */
div.css_bar_graph div.graph li.purple div.top
    {
    background: #b592dd;
    }

/* ------ bottom ------ */
div.css_bar_graph div.graph li.purple div.bottom
    {
    background: #7d47ba;
    }

/* ==================== RED BAR  ==================== */

/* ------ base ------ */
div.css_bar_graph div.graph li.red
    {
    background: #d23648;    /* --- IE --- */
    background: rgba(210,54,72,0.8);
    }

/* ------ top ------ */
div.css_bar_graph div.graph li.red div.top
    {
    background: #ea828e;
    }

/* ------ bottom ------ */
div.css_bar_graph div.graph li.red div.bottom
    {
    background: #d23648;
    }

/* ==================== HOVERS  ==================== */

div.css_bar_graph div.graph li.blue:hover
    {
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #208faf;
    }

div.css_bar_graph div.graph li.green:hover
    {
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #608d00;
    }

div.css_bar_graph div.graph li.orange:hover
    {
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #ff9000;
    }

div.css_bar_graph div.graph li.purple:hover
    {
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #7d47ba;
    }

div.css_bar_graph div.graph li.red:hover
    {
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #d23648;
    }

div.css_bar_graph div.graph li.bar:hover span
    {
    visibility: visible;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: -55px;
    margin: 0px;
    }
```

_

```
<!-- css bar graph -->
<div class="css_bar_graph">

        <!-- y_axis labels -->
        <ul class="y_axis">
            <li>0</li><li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li><li>4</li><li>5</li><li>6</li><li>7</li><li>8</li><li>9</li><li>10</li>
        </ul>

        <!-- x_axis labels -->
        <ul class="x_axis">
            <li>2011</li><li>2010</li><li>2009</li><li>2008</li>
        </ul>

        <!-- graph -->
        <div class="graph">
            <!-- grid -->
            <ul class="grid">
                <li><!-- 10 --></li>
                <li><!-- 9 --></li>
                <li><!-- 8 --></li>
                <li><!-- 7 --></li>
                <li><!-- 6 --></li>
                <li><!-- 5 --></li>
                <li><!-- 4 --></li>
                <li><!-- 3 --></li>
                <li><!-- 2 --></li>
                <li><!-- 1 --></li>
                <li class="bottom"><!-- 0 --></li>
            </ul>

            <!-- bars -->
            <!-- 250px = 100% -->
            <ul>
                <li class="bar nr_1 orange" style="height: 240px;"><div class="top"></div><div class="bottom"></div><span>9.500kg</span></li>

            </ul>   
        </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Меняете зеркально радиус кружков `<div class="top">` и `<div class="bottom">`, да ширину/высоту столбца оранжевого и готово https://jsfiddle.net/t6wgex9r/2/

Измененный код

```
div.css_bar_graph div.graph li.bar {
  width: 240px;
}

div.css_bar_graph div.graph li.bar div.top {
  width: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-radius: 10px/25px;
}

div.css_bar_graph div.graph li.bar div.bottom {
    border-radius: 10px / 25px;
    height: 100%;
    margin-right: -5px;
    width: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;

}
```

Comment: Спасибо, Ну, и второй момент бы не обойти вниманием -- ось "X" расположить сверху, список будет обновляться сверху --> вниз.  ..